# Keyboard shortcut for double-click in ABAP IDE

Tags: ide, abap

I'm taking some introductory classes on SAP/ABAP and we've been playing around with it quite well. But I can't find anywhere if there is any keyboard shortcut for double-clicking the selected object... Not even my ABAP teacher knows if there is one.

It's rather silly that I have to keep switching hands to double click something, i.e., I'm typing in a Data Element and have to double click it for details/creation. Isn't there any keyboard shortcut for this??? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of ABAP teacher is he?!?! But seriously I see lots of consultants and developers in the project who do not know such basics a bit scary if you think of it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `F2`. This dates back - well, probably an eternity.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the object correctly and press f2 or ctrl + f2.